How to retrieve the super constructor call with Konsist?
I try to check whether specific parameters are passed to parent's constructor via Konsist.
For example:
I have a ViewModel like:
class ExampleViewModel @Inject constructor(
  private val useCase1: SomeUseCase,
  private val useCase2: OtherUseCase,
) : BaseViewModel(useCase1, useCase2) { ... }

I want to check that all the useCases are passed to parent's constructor.
Is there a way to get parent constructor call out of KoClassDeclaration?
I managed to filter required properties to check as follows:
val useCaseParams = klass.primaryConstructor
                    ?.parameters
                    ?.mapNotNull { it.type.asClassDeclaration() }
                    ?.filter { it.hasParentClassOf(UseCase::class) }
                   .orEmpty()

But I can't get parent constructor declaration to check if all the use case params are passed there.

Like this:
.classes()
    .first() // KoClassDeclaration
    .parentClass
    ?.primaryConstructor
    ?.parameters

BTW Best to ask in Konsist channel at kotlinlang slack
